# Cache-Control: no-transform header in WordPress without plugin

Tags: wordpress, http-headers

How can I insert a `Cache-Control: no-transform` HTTP header in a WordPress site without using a plugin? Can it can be inserted in `.htaccess` or `function.php`?

Comment: Removed cruft from question, formatted elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the Cache-Control header with `.htaccess`, if it's being served with Apache and you have `.htaccess` enabled:

Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"